# Mismatch columns in the primary key : <target> versus <source>

Tags: c#, merge, dataset, primary-key, mismatch

While merging two DataSets in C# .net framework 4.0, it raised an error:

> *Mismatch columns in the primary key: `<target>` versus `<source>`*

My 1st Dataset is from SQL Server of datatype `Varchar`, while other is from Oracle database of datatype `Varchar2`.

```
// SQL Server database
OrgStockMaster.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { OrgStockMaster.Columns["PkID001"] };

// Oracle database 
dtOracleStock.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtOracleStock.Columns["PkID001"] };
```

While doing this,

```
dsStockMaster.Merge(StkFrmOracle);
DataSet dsDiff = dsStockMaster.GetChanges();
```

It raises this `DataException` :

> *Mismatch columns in the primary key: `<target>.PkID001` versus `<source>.PKID001`.*